# HaxeDevelop with hxml doesn't target the platform

Tags: haxe, flashdevelop

My build.hxml file looks like this:

`-main Main
-cp src
-js bin/index.js`

I use js.Browser in Main class. When I try to build it with F8, FlashDevelop gives me "You cannot access the js package while targeting cross". And I actually see that it tries to run:

`Running process: bla-bla-bla -target "js"
...
 cmd: cmd /c haxe build.hxml
 haxe  -cp src -main Main`

So it removes -js parameter from hxml and then fails the build. How to fix it?

Comment: What is the exact project configuration (Output and Build tabs of your project properties)?

Comment: Output: platform is hxml, compilation target is Application, configuration file - build.hxml, test project - Web Server. When I switch platform to hxml and try to build, FlashDevelop automatically sets pre-build command line to "cmd /c haxe $(OutputFile)", post-build command line is empty. I use FlashDevelop 5.2.0.3.

Comment: Ah, you may have to choose "Custom Build" as compilation target.

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In the project properties, choose "Custom Build" as compilation target.

The reason is that the hxml target uses a custom build command (Build tab) and when the Application compilation target is selected, FD will try to compile it a second time with an incorrect configuration. This is legitimately a bug in FD - raise an issue on Github?